# Why ball1.boundingrect.center returns the same value as ball2.boundingrect.center?

Tags: c++, qt, constants, bounding-box

I'm programming a physis simulation with circles.

***Ball.cpp Code:***

```
Ball::Ball()
{    
    angle = 0;
    setRotation(angle);

    //set the speed
    speed = 5;


    double StartX = 720;
    double StartY = 80;


        StartX = (qrand() % 800);
        StartY = (qrand() % 400);

      radius = 40;

    setTransformOriginPoint(radius,radius);

    setPos (StartX,StartY);
}

QRectF Ball::boundingRect() const
{
    return QRect(0,0,2*radius,2*radius);
}

bool Ball:: circCollide(QList <QGraphicsItem *> items) {
    QPointF c1 = mapToParent(this->boundingRect().center());

    foreach (QGraphicsItem * t, items) {
        Ball * CastBall = dynamic_cast<Ball *>(t);
        if(CastBall)
        {
            QPointF t1 = mapToScene(CastBall->boundingRect().center());
            double distance = QLineF(c1,t1).length();


            double radius1 = this->boundingRect().width() / 2;
            double radius2 = CastBall->boundingRect().width() / 2;
            double radii = radius1 + radius2;

            if ( distance <= radii )
            {
            //    qDebug() << "true collision";
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
 //   qDebug() << "false collision";
    return false;
}
```

I've got the problem that this string of code returns always the same values for the position of the center for both objects, (t1.x == c1.x , t1.y == c1.y) but `this == CastBall` returns false, so it wasn't the same object, it just has the same coordinates for the centerpoint of the boundingRect.

The coordinates are already equal before this function is called and that for all 3 objects I generate, although the sets always have a different value.

First I thought it was a problem because boundingRect is defined as a const, so I made this function in my class

```
QRectF Ball:: centerRect()
{
    return QRect(0,0,2*radius,2*radius);
}
```

and just replaced every use of boundingRect with it (was no problem since I already cast it in the method), **but it still returned the same value for both centers.**

Im really at my wits end with this one and hope to find some help.

Comment: Can you create a more minimal example? Be aware that the bounding rect is in item space coordinates and doesn't take the position of the item into account, which is defined in parent item coordinates (or scene coordinates if there's no parent).

Comment: I condensed it a lot and I do already map the center point to the scene/parent.

Comment: can you show the code where you create Balls?

Comment: Do you have this check (t1.x == c1.x , t1.y == c1.y) somewhere in the code or just judging by qDebug output?

Comment: just by qDebug Output but it also behaves like it actually was like that(always Returns true when called).

Comment: what do you mean by where i create the balls? the constructer is already there.

Comment: In the previous code (before you modified it) there was not closed if statement. Without else the ball was actually iterating over itself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87012/discussion-between-tomathor-and-alexander-tyapkov).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was following: the center of the bounding rectangle was not mapped to the coordinates of the ball. Following statement should work:

```
mapToScene(mapToItem(castBall, castBall->boundingRect().center()));
```